# Sscanf - parsing with different delimiters

Tags: c, string, io, scanf

I want parse my string using sscanf:

```
char string[] = "/home/my/estf 122,323 452,323 662,343";
```

First element of string it's path and next are ints where comma or white characters are delimiters. This is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

  char string[] = "/home/my/estf 122,323 452,323 662,343";

  char path[100];
  int int1, int2, int3, int4, int5, int6;

  sscanf(string, "%s %d[^,] %d %d[^,] %d %d[^,] %d",
          path, &int1, &int2, &int3, &int4, &int5, &int6);
  printf("Path:%s INT1:%d INT2:%d INT3:%d INT4:%d INT5:%d INT6:%d\n",
          path, int1, int2, int3, int4, int5, int6);
  return 0;
}
```

What it's wrong? Is it possible to extend it, to parse dynamic numbers of ints (no 6 exactly) and store it in integer array?

Comment: `"%s %d,%d %d,%d %d,%d"`

Comment: Well I don't know sscanf but my guess would be you need to remove the spaces between `%d[^,]` and  `%d`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, thx it works. But is it possible to extend it, to parse dynamic numbers of ints and store it in integer array?

Comment: It should be changed to repeat.

Comment: @SDJMcHattie, I tried to do that but it wasn't working.

Comment: You can read the entire line as a string. Then finding delimiters and using  `atoi();` get the data you are looking for. `strtok()`?

Comment: might be easier to just write a function which manually parses it instead of using `sscanf()`

Comment: I made this using strtok() but my code was very long and I try to make it simpler...

Comment: @ABLUE PIXY, what's mean specifically? It can be done without loop?

Comment: @bentank, I know atoi but how can I find delimiters?

Comment: You know what they are right? It this example it seems they are a space and comma. You can walk the string looking for `' '` or `','`.

Comment: It must be repeated to read in the case of the data of undefined length.

Comment: @rowan.G, thanks for your advice. I'll try to do it manually. Would you have to give me example as can I start to do this?

Comment: Check out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
char a[3][16], z;
int b[8] = {0};
char x[] = "/home/my/estf 122,323 452,323 662,343", y[64];
sscanf(x, "%c %[^/ ,] %c %[^/] %c %[^/ ] %d %c %d %d %c %d %d %c %d", &z, a[0], &z, a[1], &z, a[2], &b[0], &z, &b[1],  &b[2], &z, &b[3],  &b[4], &z, &b[5]);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%s ", a[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; b[i] != 0; i++) {
    printf("%d ", b[i]);
}
```

There may be better methods to do this, but using sscanf you have do this way. You may even convert the really long `sscanf` line into a loop.

When using sscanf, you must consume the characters you're specifying in the negated scanset. So in case of a scanset like this: [^/] will read all the characters upto the first occurence of `/`. But, pointer will be still at the `/` in the source string. You must consume that `/` and continue reading ahead.

for more information on how sscanf works, look at `man sscanf`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to extend it, to parse dynamic numbers of ints (no 6
>   exactly) and store it in integer array?

You can use `strtol` in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "/home/my/estf 122,323 452,323 662,343";
    char path[100];
    int ai[32];
    char *ptr;
    int n = 0;

    ptr = strchr(str, ' ');
    sprintf(path, "%.*s", ptr - str, str);
    while (*ptr) {
        ai[n++] = (int)strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10);
        if (*ptr) ptr++;
    }
    printf("Path:%s", path);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf(" INT%d=%d", i + 1, ai[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to be using something like `strtok()`

Here is this [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) slightly modified:

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  char string[] = "/home/my/estf 122,323 452,323 662,343";
  char * pch;

  pch = strtok (string, " ,");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,");
    if (pch)
    {
        int val = atoi(pch);
        printf ("%d\n", val);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```